# Is it safe to access a variable declared in an inner scope by pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, scope

The program below prints

```
root 3                                                                                                                                                        
next 11
```

However, I am not sure if the program keeps root.next until the end of the program.

```
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct sequence
{
    int x;
    sequence* next;
}sequence;

int main()
{

   sequence root;
   root.x = 3;
   {
       sequence p;
       p.x = 11;
       root.next = &p;
   }

   printf("root %d\n",root.x);
   printf("next %d\n",root.next->x);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scope of `p` ends at the closing bracket.

```
{
    sequence p;
    p.x = 11;
    root.next = &p;
} <---- here
```

When you call `printf("next %d\n",root.next->x);` the variable `p` you are pointing to with `root.next` doesn't exist anymore. Therefore it isn't "safe", since it causes undefined behavior.

Comment: So does it mean that  "printf" prints the correct result only because the value in the address is not overwritten?

Comment: @ergoilto Take a look at the generated assembly. As far as C is concerned it is undefined.

Comment: "undefined behaviour" can mean **anything**, including the thing you hoped for. never count on that, the next time it could start a thermonuclear war

Comment: @ergoilto The non-pedantic answer is yes.