# Block level variable scope and lifeline while using a pointer reference

Tags: c, pointers, scope

Following is the simplest code producing two different output,

1. 10 ( Turbo C Version 3.0 )
2. 0 ( online compiler [ideone](https://ideone.com/aixT5W)

CODE

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
   int *j;
   {
       int i = 10;
       j = &i;
   }
   printf("%d",*j);
}
```

Is this part of the **undefined behaviour** that another [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28736448/is-it-safe-to-access-a-variable-declared-in-an-inner-scope-by-pointer) says ?

> As per the referenced question, `printf` produces the output 10 only
>   because there is no other program/system that overwrites the same
>   piece of memory.

Comment: Why are you using the old compiler Turbo C? that version is quite old and would produce different result to the more modern one used behind ideone? Not alone that, one is 89 standard, the later version would be 99 standard.

Comment: @t0mm13b - While I agree with encouraging use of more modern compilers, that code yields undefined behaviour from all versions of the C standard.   The age of compilers would only matter if the behaviour was undefined in one version of the C standard, and well defined in another - which is not the case here.

Comment: In practice, many compilers will allocate storage for inner-scope variables at function entry and release it at function exit, so even though `i` goes out of scope at the end of the loop, storage is still allocated for it.  However, that behavior is *not* guaranteed and should not be relied upon.  The behavior in your code is indeed undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the answer to that question you linked to is correct.  The result is undefined behaviour.   In ALL versions of the C standard.

The variable `i` ceases to exist, as far as your program is concerned, at the end of the block that contains it.

The value of `j` is therefore an address of something that has ceased to exist.  Evaluating `*j` therefore gives undefined behaviour.

One possible symptom of undefined behaviour is output that varies between compilers.   There are many other possible symptoms since, formally, ANYTHING is allowed to happen when the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: I disagree, that is down to ANSI C 89 standards which Turbo C 3 reflected on vs the ANSI C 99 standards based on scoping rules.

Comment: The scoping rules (with respect to variables defined in basic blocks in `{` and `}`) did not change.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9513604/declare-c89-local-variables-in-the-beginning-of-the-scope) also, see [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) under section 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects .

Comment: @t0mm13b I don't see anything in either link which says that `i` is still in scope outside the block it's defined in.